# Does free sugar intake before meals cause more adverse effects than after them?

Tags: digestion, diabetes, sugar, time-of-day, meal

The WHO gives [sugar intake recommendations](http://www.who.int/nutrition/publications/guidelines/sugars_intake/en/) in terms of percentage of energy intake. That, combined with some popular wisdom makes the think that it isn't the same if I eat, say a chocolate bar, before or after lunch.

From what I understand, the major problem with free sugars is that they cause an insoline production spike that our body is not quite prepared to deal with in the long run. If I were to eat some *not so unhealty food* (such as a regular meal), the insuline levels would rise at a normal pace until the free sugar intake and would drop less after the sugar processing, because there would still be the rest of the meal to digest, effectively reducing the insuline spike.

So, it is worse to consume free sugars before a meal than after? If so, how much worse is it? For the same ammount of adverse effects, can I ingest more free sugars after a regular meal than after a small one?

**NOTE:** please consider as meals something a nutricionist would recommend to an average, healthy adult person, a "regular meal" being the lunch, and the small meal the mid-morning break.

Comment: Well my intuition tells me that eating sugar after meal gives a higher increase in blood sugar but shorter length, since it takes some time for blood sugar to rise when eating a whole meal while eating before gives a pro longed rise in blood sugar. Unfortunately I couldn't find any references to back this up.